# Designing "hot or not" style database in Entity Framework Model First

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, database-design, ef-model-first

I want to design a duel of sorts between movies so that two are pitched against each other, the user selects the better one which then gets a point. In the database I want a list of all movies that have dueled and how many times they have won respectively.

**Movie**

```
    Id
    Name
    Duels
```

**Duel**

```
    ContenderOne
    ContenderTwo
    NumberOfDuels
    ContenderOneWins
    ContenderTwoWins
```

I'm trying to set this up so that the movie entity has 1 property called Duels in which I can fetch all duel entities where it is involved, regardless of it being contender one or contender two. ContenderOne and ContenderTwo should link back to the movies.

Any ideas how to achieve this? I am stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have just one property. You will need two: `DuelsAsContenderOne` and `DuelsAsContenderTwo`. If you need all duels disregarding the position, you can use the expression `x.DuelsAsContenderOne.Concat(x.DuelsAsContenderTwo)`

Comment: Ok, I'll just add that as a method on the class then. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Solved by setting the "duplicate" properties to private and adding a partial which return the concat result.